# reformating csv with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following code:

```
#Import Modoules
from shutil import copyfile
import pandas as pd

#Read new sample
col_list = ['Use%']
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', usecols=col_list)

#Open Existing file and rename headers
partition_df = pd.read_csv('output.csv', names=['Server Name', 'Date' ,'Disk     Size', 'Mounted on', 'M-1 Usage %', 'M-2 Usage %', 'M-3 Usage %', 'M-4 Usage %', 'M-5 Usage %','M-6 Usage %', 'M-7 Usage %', 'M-8 Usage %', 'M-9 Usage %', 'M-10 Usage %', 'M-11 Usage %', 'M-12 Usage %', 'Temp'], header=1)

#insert new Sample
partition_df.insert(loc=4, column='Current % Usage', value=df)

#Drop Temp Column
partition_df.drop(['Temp'], axis=1, inplace=True)

#Drop empty Column
partition_df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)

#Write new Sample file
partition_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)

#copy output file to disk_check.csv
copyfile('output.csv', 'disk_usage.csv')
```

file temp.csv is

```
Use%
20%
30%
23%
```

file output.csv is

```
Server Name,Date,Disk Size,Mounted On,Current Usage  %
s4prd1,30/11/2020,15G,/usr/sap,17%
s4prd2,30/11/2020,2.0G,/var,1%
s4prd2,30/11/2020,15G,/usr/sap,16%
```

I need the final output.csv file to be with the new column which was 'Use %' as 'current usage %' at column 5, and the older columns to advance 1 column further
after first run it should look like that:

```
Server Name,Date,Disk Size,Mounted On,Current Usage  %,M-1 Usage %
s4prd1,30/11/2020,15G,/usr/sap,20%,17%
s4prd2,30/11/2020,2.0G,/var,30%,1%
s4prd2,30/11/2020,15G,/usr/sap23%,16%
```

I don't want to insert empty columns which I succeeded in doing on tests. but when I try to run it on production it gives me the error on the code -     #Open Existing file and rename headers - because there's no data in these columns.

sorry for the bad english :)

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to add the new 'current usage' and shift the older ones forward and change their names respectively. If so, I can suggest changing the column names first, so the previous 'current usage' will turn into 'M-1 usage' and so on:

```
static_columns = ['Server Name', 'Date', 'Disk Size', 'Mounted On']
partition_df.columns = static_columns + ['M-{} Usage%'.format(i) for i in range(1, (len(df.columns)-len(static_columns))+1)]
```

Then you can simply insert the new data as 'current usage':

```
partition_df.insert(loc=4, column = 'Current Usage%', value=df)
```